# Checking if path ends in separation

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm setting up a small script to merge PDFs in a folder that has a cover letter, resume, and references. I'm wondering if there's a Python method that can look at the path string and detect if it ends in a /, and if not I can add the / to it. For example-

```
dircheck = raw_input("Directory with cover, resume, and references:")
if dircheck (has no slash at end):
    homedir = dircheck + os.sep
else:
    dircheck = homedir
```

Comment: You don't normally *need* to add `os.sep`; use `os.path.join()` when constructing paths and separators will be added as needed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if not dircheck.endswith(os.sep):
    homedir = dircheck + os.sep
else:
    dircheck = homedir
```

Alternatively, `os.path.join` an empty path to it:

```
os.path.join(dircheck, "")
```

---

```
# Unix

In [31]: os.path.join("asd/", "")
Out[31]: 'asd/'

In [32]: os.path.join("asd", "")
Out[32]: 'asd/'

# Windows

>>> os.path.join("asdasd/", "")
'asdasd/'
>>> os.path.join("asdasd\\", "")
'asdasd\\'
>>> os.path.join("asdasd", "")
'asdasd\\'
```